# Pasted XML to JSON jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I am working on this project, user pastes xml into a textarea, jQuery parses the xml > converts to json because I have something to work with for a nice JSON viewer.

I researched stackoverflow and many of the people asking this question are referred to the
xml to json plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

I'm having an issue with it. This version only seems to accept the first argument as quoted text for a save file on your machine. When I change it from a saved file, to my existing parsed variable or use $xml it doesn't work.

Here is my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dnVQs/
The sample xml is already set to the value of the text area.

Thank you in advance!

This is doesn't work. When I run an alert on $xml I get [object Object]

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    $.get($xml, function (xml) {
       var animals = $.xml2json(xml);
       alert(animals.dog[1].name + '/' + animals.dog[1]); 
   });   
});
```

This is the example that post uses which I can get to work, but again not for what I need.

```
$.get('location/yourfilename.xml', function(xml) {
    var animals = $.xml2json(xml);
    alert(animals.dog[1].name + '/' + animals.dog[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a $.get() on it.  You can save the content of the text box to a variable and just do var animals = $.xml2json(xml) where xml is the value of the text box.  Using your jsfiddle example:

```
 var myxml = $.parseXML($("#textbox1").val());

 var animals = $.xml2json(myxml);
 alert(animals.dog[1].name + '/' + animals.dog[1]);
```